# How to configure vite.config to proxy a server at a different port

Tags: reactjs, flask, server, proxy, vite

I am trying to fetch data from a Flask server (localhost:5000) with my Vite app (localhost:5173). All of my API endpoints work in Postman. I followed instructions from Vite's documentation, however, I must be missing something, because the fetch still sends requests to localhost:5173.

Here is vite.config.ts:

```
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  server: {
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        ws: true,
        configure: (proxy, _options) => {
          proxy.on('error', (err, _req, _res) => {
            console.log('proxy error', err);
          });
          proxy.on('proxyReq', (proxyReq, req, _res) => {
            console.log('Sending Request to the Target:', req.method, req.url);
          });
          proxy.on('proxyRes', (proxyRes, req, _res) => {
            console.log('Received Response from the Target:', proxyRes.statusCode, req.url);
          });
        }
      },
    }
  }
})
```

These are the client-side console outputs from the error-handling in vite.config:

```
Sending Request to the Target: GET /api/home/
Received Response from the Target: 200 /api/home/
```

This is my fetch:

```
fetch('/api/home')
      .then((res) => console.log(res))
    // .then((res) => res.json())
    // .then((data: object[]) => {
    //   setPostData(data)
    // })
```

This is the output of the above console.log (confused why the fetch still hits the localhost:5173 endpoint):

```
type: 'basic', 
url: 'http://localhost:5173/api/home/', 
redirected: true, 
status: 200,  ok: true, …
```

This is some data, as it responds in Postman:

```
[{
        "comments": [],
        "created_at": "Thu, 23 Mar 2023 08:30:17 GMT",
        "likes": 2,
        "text": "Lorem ipsum",
        "title": "Morbi non quam nec dui luctus rutrum",
        "updated_at": "Thu, 23 Mar 2023 08:30:17 GMT",
        "user": "alesmonde0",
        "user_id": 1
    }]
```

I am fairly new to Flask, new to TypeScript, but have experience with React/Vite using Express and Node instead.
Am I missing something simple?

I have tried:

- Following the documentation on Vite
- Changing the server.proxy path in vite.config to '/' - this serves only my Flask app, with no Vite
- Adding `secure: false` to vite.config - a solution I found on a similar question - this didn't work
- Adding `ws: true` to vite.config - another solution I found here - didn't work
- Changing server.proxy url from '/api' to '/' - this served my Flask app and I was unable to see my Vite front-end
- Adding Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers to my fetch - this did nothing
- Adding server.proxy.configure options to attempt to find an error - this confusingly responds with 200 - I expected a 400

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by using Axios. This required only configuring the Axios module itself versus having to configure the vite.config file.

Fetch in react component:

```
import axios from 'axios';

async function fetch() {
      const res = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', {
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      });
      setPostData(res.data);
    }
```

I also had to implement flask-CORS on the server-side in order to avoid the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' error:

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
```